# Can't understand why i'm getting an incorrect syntax error in my script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting an incorrect syntax error for the line

```
SELECT * INTO @pre_and_post_op FROM NBOCAP(@StartDate,@EndDate,@OrgCode)
```

Code:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
DECLARE @EndDate datetime
DECLARE @OrgCodeString varchar (8000)

SET @StartDate = '01-JAN-11'
SET @EndDate = '31-MAR-14'
SET @OrgCodeString = 'RA720|RQ801|RVJ20|RN325|8AAAA|RBA11'

DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @OrgCode varchar(10)
DECLARE @OrgCount int

DECLARE @TrustTable TABLE
(idx int IDENTITY(1,1), org varchar(10))

DECLARE @pre_and_post_op TABLE
(CARE_ID int,ERR_NumberOfNodesPositive int,ERR_FinalPathologyTCategory int,
ERR_FinalPathologyNCategory int,ERR_FinalMCategory int)

INSERT INTO @TrustTable
SELECT * FROM SplitString(@OrgCodeString, '|')

SET @i = 1
SET @OrgCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TrustTable)
IF @OrgCount > 0
WHILE (@i <= @OrgCount)

BEGIN
    SET @OrgCode = (SELECT org FROM @TrustTable WHERE idx = @i)
    SELECT * INTO @pre_and_post_op FROM NBOCAP(@StartDate,@EndDate,@OrgCode)
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot `SELECT INTO` a table variable. To quote [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx):

> You cannot specify a table variable or table-valued parameter as the new table.

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` instead

```
INSERT INTO @pre_and_post_op SELECT * FROM NBOCAP(@StartDate,@EndDate,@OrgCode)
```